# How to get GPS coords on button click ? (most simple)

Tags: ios, gps

i tried to implement GPS functionality into my app using the few tutorials.

I do it by using this:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_location_handling.htm

Gps coords are obtained after start of the app.

But problem is that, i am not able to call GPS coords again after button click, it means somethong like:

```
- (IBAction)getGpsCoords:(id)sender {

   [[LocationHandler getSharedInstance]setDelegate:self];
   [[LocationHandler getSharedInstance]startUpdating];

}
```

How should be right solution? I will glad id somebody can explain how to do it better (with some good example or link).

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're having difficulty doing. You don't say what `LocationHandler` is, but the flow is pretty much correct:

1. Start location services
2. A delegate method gets called periodically as the location information changes

You can't just tap a button and get the current location; that's not how the API works. I suppose you could start location services when the app starts and record the current location in a singleton (like your `LocationHandler` class?) and just call that when you press the button?

Comment: @Jiri You don't say what `LocationHandler` does and you don't show your code for the delegate so it's difficult to add anything more. But the bottom line it: _this is how it's supposed to work_. If no more updates arrive in your delegate it's because the OS doesn't think there's been any significant change in location.

Comment: O.K, thanks for explanation, is possible to add here some short guide, how to get GPS coords after button click?